# How to fix ajax call to get user id returns undefined if same url works directly in browser?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, ajax

I have an array with a few user email addresses in it, trying to iterate through the array and get Ids. Console log is telling me xuser is undefined.

When I manually enter the url below into the browser with an email from the array I get the desired xml result, with users id.

```
EmailArray.forEach(GetUserId);

function GetUserId(item) {

  console.log(item);
  $.ajax({ 
    url: xhost + "/portal/_api/web/SiteUsers?$select=Id&$filter=Email eq '" + item + "'",
    type: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", },
    success: function (data) {
      var xuser = data.d.Id;
      console.log(xuser);
    },
    error: function (error) { alert(JSON.stringify(error)); }
  });
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: figured it out literally 30 seconds after posting, will mark as answer after 24 hrs...

Answer (score 1):

Changing as below returned desired results.

```
var xuser = data.d.results[0].Id;
```